# Name of sound-induced-hunger condition

Tags: experimental-psychology, psychiatry, conditioning, feeding, medication

When I was a student I used to notice that towards supper time, whenever I would go from my quiet study space to a place where people were talking, it people started to tell in my quiet space, i would get hungry.

Recently, I have tried the TalkBack feature on my Android device, and found, that whenever I am lying in bed, time with my stomach, and not feeling hungry, after turning TalkBack on and using it, my hunger level peaks to 100% excruciating hunger, after just five minutes of using TalkBack.

On average I can hear mild sounds in my room throughout the day and they don't bother me, (with just one or two mild exceptions, which might induce a very feather-light hunger feeling towards the evening).

I also have a generic form of misophonia whereby generic noises trigger distress, or even when pleasant, tend to alter it modify my thoughts, while some mild ones seem to pleasantly accompany or suggest or improve my thought performance in some respects in some situations.

However, I have never analyzed the hunger component before formally in a post (especially with relationship to this Android TalkBack feature).

My question is, is there a technical name for the form of extreme sound-induced-hunger I describe?

(Hunger can also be induced by medication, but that's another issue).

Thanks.

Comment: [Stress can induce huger and/or a change in food preferences](https://www.popsci.com/science/article/2013-09/fyi-does-stress-make-you-hungry). Since you say noise causes you stress... it's probably an indirect effect... which probably means there's no name for it.

Answer (score 3):

Probably not. The closest thing I am aware of is [Mayor et al (2016) [The Effect of Chronic Dieting Goals on Auditory Perceptual Biases]](http://www.acrwebsite.org/volumes/v44/acr_vol44_1021143.pdf) where they

> propose the existence of “wishful hearing,” which establishes that ambient product sounds can be perceived as more spatially proximal when more desirable and thus lead to increased purchase intentions and consumption.

Comment: If I were to list, the perceived pleasure, it would be 1. spatially proximal, 2. increased purchase intention, 3. consumption, 4. more desirable sounds

Comment: In order of importance 1. more desirable sounds 2. purchase intentions, 3. spatially proximal

Comment: Therefore, you could write, another, paper (on this).